# Burkholder's inequality on $[s,t]$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, quadratic-variation

Let $T>0$, $F$ be an adapted squared-integrable process and $p\ge 2$, then the Burkholder's inequality implies
$$
E\bigg(\bigg|\int_0^T F(s)dB(s)\bigg|^p\bigg)\le C(p) E\bigg[\bigg(\int_0^T F^2(s)ds\bigg)^{p/2}\bigg], 
$$
for some constant $C(p)$.

I was wondering why most textbooks present the inequality from $[0,T]$, instead of any subinterval $[s,t]\subset[0,T]$. I follow the proof and I didn't notice any technical difficulty to extend the result to the integral on $[s,t]$:
$$
E\bigg(\bigg|\int_s^t F(r)dB(r)\bigg|^p\bigg)\le C(p) E\bigg[\bigg(\int_s^t F^2(r)dr\bigg)^{p/2}\bigg].
$$
Did I overlook anything? Or the result on $[s,t]$ is a simple consequence of the result on $[0,t]$?

Similarly, I was wondering whether the $L^p$ estimate of Levy integral:
$$E\bigg(\bigg|\int_0^T\int_E F(s)d\tilde{N}(ds,de)\bigg|^p\bigg),$$
the so-called Kunita's inequality, works on arbitrary fixed finite interval $[s,t]$.

Comment: The inequality for subintervals $[s,t]$ is indeed a direct and simple consequence of the result on $[0,T]$; simply apply the inequality on $[0,T]$ to the truncated function $\tilde{F}(r) := F(r) 1_{[s,t]}(r)$.

Comment: @saz Thank you very much. How stupid of I!